# Android: How to temporarily present a programaticly created bitmap for debug?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-alertdialog, dialog

I'm Creating a bitmap programmaticly.
How can i see them for debug purpose before I use them further?
I was thinking something like a dialogBox or an AlertDialog, but how can i make them to show a bitmap?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `ImageView` and set a bitmap to be the content.

[ImageView#setImageBitmap(Bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

This whole thing should be able to be put into an `AlertDialog` if you would like.